# Syntax error when creating a MySQL function

Tags: mysql, function

I'm trying to create a function in MySQL, but getting a syntax error. This is my function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION gg () 
RETURNS char(8)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE cod varchar(8);
  select RIGHT(MAX(idCurso),7) into cod from Curso;
  IF cod is null then
        set cod = 'C' + right('0000000' + convert(varchar(7),1),7);
    else
        set cod = 'C' + right('0000000' + convert(varchar(7), @id +1),7)
    return cod;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting this error in the `set cod` after the `if cod is null then`:

> "cod" is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: share the error

Comment: @Mario, can you explain what you want to achieve with this line `set cod = 'C' + right('0000000' + convert(varchar(7),1),7);`

Comment: Last I checked, MySQL does not use `+` for concatenation; but it's been a while since I checked. Also, it looks like the arguments for `CONVERT` might be backwards...and you have no `END IF` _Make sure you are using documentation for MySQL, not MSSQL, nor Oracle, nor sqlite, etc.._

Comment: + is an arithmetic operator in mysql use concat instead.You aren't terminating your second set statement and your first set statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JitendraYadav I'm trying to create an id with this structure: 'C000000X' being 'x' a consecutive number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many issues with your function.

- `+` icon doesn't perform concatenation in MySQL, it is used for sum. Use [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) or [CONCAT_WS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) for the same.
- Improper use of `CONVERT`. Please see documentation [CONVERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert)
- Use [LPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) to pad `0` to the left of your integer value and make it length to `7`.
- Removed `@a`, don't know from where you're accessing it, replaced it with `cod` value and adding 1 to it.
- Missed `END IF` clause.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION gg () RETURNS CHAR(8) DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE cod VARCHAR(8);
    SELECT
        RIGHT(MAX(idCurso),7) INTO cod
    FROM Curso; 

    IF cod IS NULL THEN 
        SET cod = CONCAT('C', LPAD(1, 7, '0')); 
    ELSE 
        SET cod = CONCAT('C', LPAD(cod + 1, 7, '0')); 
    END IF; 
    RETURN cod; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @MarioVasquez, happy to help. For any MySQL statement, check whether it is right and how to use it. This is the best way to learn.